# Generating salt with specified bit length

Tags: c#, passwords, cryptography, salt

I got a method that's supposed to generate a 64 byte (512 bit) salt for me:

```
public static string GenerateSalt()
{
    var rngCrypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[64];
    rngCrypto.GetBytes(saltBytes);

    string result = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

    return result;
}
```

This seems to be running fine, the `saltBytes` bytearray has the size of 64 byte. However, I can't enter the results in my MS SQL Database Table, consisting of a `char(64)` typed column.

My assumption is, that the `Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);` method is faulty on my side, but I'd like to know how I can improve this. A quick run through `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(secondSalt);` reveals a string size of 176 byte instead of 64 byte.

Comment: 64 byte salts is overkill. Even 16 bytes is plenty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte array is logically a number in base 256. Converting that to a number in base 64 is going to make it longer. Just like when you convert from hex F0 to binary 1111111100000000, it gets longer.

If you want to store the salt in the database in a human-readable base-64-encoded string then it is going to have to be much longer than 64 single-byte characters.

As for running it through the ASCII encoder -- I have no idea what you're trying to do here. That sounds like an odd thing to do to non-textual data.  Can you explain?

Comment: Well, how should I then save the salt and the password? As SQL `binary`?

Comment: @SeToY: Is it logically *binary data*? If so, then storing it as binary data sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: Well... Is it logically binary data? Is a salt **and a password** logically binary data? I've seen this guide telling me to use base64: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#aspsourcecode

Comment: @SeToY Eric's right (as he usually is).  If it's binary data, storing it in a binary field in a table is a good idea.  The only time you'd want to use Base64 encoding is if you're trying to transmit it via a mechanism that doesn't handle binary data well - like sending it as part of an HTTP query string for instance.

Comment: @Corey I wasn't really sure if it's really binary data, that's why I asked. Sorry if it sounded harsh. I'd have to admit, sending a salt or a password as part of an HTTP query string sounds like a really terrible idea. But all-in-all, you're suggesting saving the SHA512 password and salt as a binary(64) in MS SQL? I don't know how then my checking would look like (now: **DoHash(password+salt)**)

Comment: @SeToY Store the salt value as a `binary(64)`, store the password as text if that's what it is.  They are two values that are needed to decrypt the message.  If you want to store them together in a single field then you can use a `varchar` field that's large enough to hold the values once converted to strings, or a binary field with the right size.  There's no one **right** way, it depends on your requirements.

Comment: @Corey Sorry, I still don't get it. I'm not bound to any requirements, so the best way to do it should be the way I end up doing it. After I've read along, I assume SHA256 (or SHA512) is the **wrong** way to do it, I should be using Rfc2898DeriveBytes instead?

Comment: Actually he sends it through the `UTF-16` decoder, confusingly accessed via the `ASCIIEncoding` class.

Comment: If you are trying to store a byte array, store it as binary.  If you are string to store a char array or a string, store it as text.  If you are trying to pass a byte array to a function that needs a string or char array, encode it.  If you are trying to pass an encoded string or char array to a function that needs a byte array, decode it.  That said, if this is for a production application you should try using an existing username/password framework.  For example, on an asp.net website I recommend Microsoft's membership framework.

Answer (score 3):

When you start with 64 bytes (512 bits), then convert to base 64, you're storing only 6 bits in each byte, so you need ceiling(512/6) = 86 bytes to store the result (not sure where your 176 bytes is coming from though).

Comment: The 176 bytes is coming from the fact that base 64 adds padding so that it's a multiple of 4, so it's really 88 characters not 86.  Then, if you're using Unicode encoding there are 2 bytes to a character: 88 x 2 = 176.